# matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar is throwing an error it shouldn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, errorbar

I'm trying to make an errorbar plot with my data. X is a 9 element ndarray. Y and Yerr are 9x5 ndarrays. When I call:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar(X, Y, Yerr)
```

I get a ValueError: "yerr must be a scalar, the same dimensions as y, or 2xN."

But `Y.shape == Yerr.shape` is True.

I'm running on 64 bit Windows 7 with Spyder 2.3.8 and Python 3.5.1. Matplotlib is up to date. I've installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

Any ideas?

Edit: Some data.

```
X=numpy.array([1,2,3])
Y=numpy.array([[1,5,2],[3,6,4],[9,3,7]])
Yerr=numpy.ones_like(Y)
```

Comment: include some code that generates example data that triggers this issue

Comment: Hmmm... the error message does not agree with the docstring, which says `*xerr*/*yerr*: [ scalar | N, Nx1, or 2xN array-like ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe by "dimension of y" the docs actually meant 1xN...

Anyway, this could work:

```
for y, yerr in zip(Y, Yerr):
    matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar(X, y, yerr)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hmmm....**

By studying lines 2962-2965 of the module that raises the error we find

```
if len(yerr) > 1 and not ((len(yerr) == len(y) and not (iterable(yerr[0]) and len(yerr[0]) > 1)))
```

From the data

```
1 T len(yerr) > 1
2 T len(yerr) == len(y)
3 T iterable(yerr[0])
4 T len(yerr[0]) > 1
5 T 1 and not (2 and not (3 and 4)
```

However, this will not be triggered if the following test is not passed:

```
if (iterable(yerr) and len(yerr) == 2 and
                iterable(yerr[0]) and iterable(yerr[1])):
....
```

And it is not triggered, because len(yerr) = 3

Everything seems to check out, except for the dimensionality. This works:

```
X = numpy.tile([1,2,3],3)
Y = numpy.array([1,5,2,3,6,4,9,3,7])
Yerr = numpy.ones_like(Y)
```

I am not sure what causes the error. The "l0, = " assignment also seems a little quirky.